# Ember.js how to call super class or base class method from subclass?

Tags: ember.js

When ever i try to call a base class method from subclass in ember.js I get the following error

Assertion failed: Ember.Object.create no longer supports defining methods that call _super

```
App.BaseClass = Ember.Object.extend({
 sayHello: function(){
   //my code
}
});

App.SubClass = App.BaseClass.extend({
//some code here 

sayHellow: function(){
//some code of subclass
.
.
.
this_super(); // This causes error: Assertion failed: Ember.Object.create no //longer supports defining methods that call _super
}
});
```

Comment: Is `this_super` a typo? Is `Hello` vs. `Hellow` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

you should use this._super()

```
sayHello: function(){

//some code of subclass

.

.

.

this._super(); 

// This causes error: Assertion failed: Ember.Object.create no //longer supports defining methods that call _super

}

});
```

Comment: Dear I am already using this._super() which causes Assertion failed error

Comment: your using this_super()